# vbNewLine in a div

Tags: html, vb.net, model-view-controller, newline

I want to use a controller to print

```
test1
test2
```

inside a `<div>`... right now all I have is a simple

```
Return "test1" & vbNewLine & "test2"
```

but this code returns the words on a single line albeit with a space (like `test1 test2`).

How do I do this? I've tried changing the div into a span, that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to add a `<br />` instead. A browser won't interpret a `vbNewLine` to a break in HTML. It will remove most whitespace automatically, including newlines.

```
Return "test1<br />test2"
```

or

```
Return field1 & "<br />" & field2 ' depending on your setup.
```

Can you give more details of what your page is doing if this isn't the solution?